# System.UnauthorizedAccessException while creating file in app folder

Tags: .net, winforms

I have Winforms application that must create write to certain configuration file during usage. Once i use debug mode this file can be create and written to it but once i create Setup Project and actually install the application i cannot access with following exception.

Configuration file is located the same directory as program ( at Program Files )

Code i'm using to read/write is.

```
public static string[] GetDefaultConfigFile(string path)
{
    string[] res = {};
    if (File.Exists(GetInternalFileName(path)))
    {
        using (StreamReader tr = new StreamReader(GetInternalFileName(path)))
        {
            res = tr.ReadToEnd().Split(';');
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public static void SaveDefaultConfigFile(string fileName, string path)
{
    using (var tw = new StreamWriter(GetInternalFileName(path)))
    {
        tw.Write(fileName);
        tw.Close();
    }
}

private static string GetInternalFileName(string path)
{
    return path + "\\setup.config";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the account used to run this code doesn't have sufficient privileges to write to the specified folder (`Program Files`). If you are running under Windows 7 or Vista standard users are not authorized to write to this folder. In this case you could use the user [specific folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) `c:\users\username` to store configuration settings.

Also I would simplify:

```
public static string[] GetDefaultConfigFile(string path)
{
    return File.ReadAllText(path).Split(';');
}

public static void SaveDefaultConfigFile(string fileName, string path)
{
    File.WriteAllText(path, fileName);
}

private static string GetInternalFileName(string path)
{
    return Path.Combine(path, "setup.config");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to force application to start with Administrator privileges?

Comment: @eugeneK, yes, when you run the application you right click on the executable and select Run as Administrator. Or in tghe properties of the shortcut I think there is a checkbox in the Compatibility tab where you could force this shortcut to always run as administrator. In this case it will prompt the user for admin password everytime he runs the shortcut.

Comment: i don't have run application as Administrator for this application. Moreover there is a folder inside of application folder where nLog successfully writes logs to.

Comment: @eugeneK, in this case you could try granting read/write permissions to the folder you want to write. I don't know what you expect me to say more. The program doesn't have sufficient privileges to write to this folder.

Comment: How can i give such permissions? I tried to create app.manifest in which i required Administrator access but application doesn't show GUI as uiAccess is false, when i set it to true i get an error.

Comment: @eugeneK, when you install the application as administrator you could add the required permissions to the target folder. But to be honest the recommended way to do this is to use the special folders to store user specific settings. That's why they were created in Windows 7.